# NullPointerException for Android Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I had a previous question similar to my current problem, and that was when I retrieved null values from my String arrays, now my problem is that I think I'm also getting null values from my integar arrays, but I do not know how to handle such an exception, for example:

```
for int(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(taskArr[i] != null){
        taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
        taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
    }
    }
```

the `if(taskArr[i] != null)` solved my problem for getting null values from my String Array, but it does not seem to working on my integar arrays. taskArr[] is my string array, taskId[] is my integar array and taskArray[] is an edittext array

Comment: An integer array cannot contains nulls (unless you used Integer[] instead of integer[]).  If these are integer arrays, how does this work? `taskArray[i].getText()`

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that taskArray[] is an edittext array

Comment: Don't only mention this in the comments, edit the question and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because an `int` cannot be `null`, but an `Integer` can. I assume your `taskArray.getId()` returns an `Integer`, but `taskId` is `int[]`. Thus you're casting directly to `int`, which will fail if the `Integer` is `null`. This line

```
taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
```

is equivalent with

```
taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId().intValue();
```

What happens here if `taskArray[i].getId()` is null?

You need to get an `Integer`, check if it's `null`, then assign to an `int` if you want if it's not `null`. For example:

```
Integer id = taskArray[i].getId();
if (id != null) {
    taskId[i] = id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional if statement only applies to the first line you need to use brackets.  In general its a good practice to use brackets with your if statements, it makes things more intuitive and saves you from encountering errors like this.  You will also want to check that `getText()` is not null.

```
for int(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(taskArr[i] != null && taskArr[i].getText() != null)
        {
           taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
           taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
        }
    }
```

On a side note you mentioned that your array contained `Integer` objects.  I'm not seeing `Integer.getText()` or `Integer.getId()` on the API documentation for `Integer` is another type being stored in the array?

Comment: even with the curly brackets I get a nullpointerexception error ):

Comment: @AnthonyWu Thats because getText() could be null, I thought you were using an Integer array from your questions, I'll update.

Comment: @AnthonyWu check my answer, I think that's your problem. You should give more details in your question, like the full stacktrace.

Comment: Or getId() could be null... The question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You commented:

> i'm still getting a syntax error for that ...

This is not valid Java:

```
for int(i=0;i<n;i++) {
}
```

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
}
```

---

As for the rest, if you told us exactly which line the NPE was being thrown on, we could probably tell you what it is causing it.  You seem to be implying that it is this line:

```
    taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
```

If that is the case, and if `taskId` and `taskArray` have types `int[]` and `EditText[]` then there are 3 possibilities:

```
- `taskId` is `null`,
- `taskArray` is `null`, or 
- `taskArray[i]` is `null`.
```

If we assume that the previous line:

```
    taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
```

did not throw an NPE, that eliminates two possibilities, leaving `taskId` as the culprit.

---

The other comment I want to make is that all of this testing for nulls to avoid NPE's is most likely the wrong approach.  You should be finding out where these `null` values are coming from and changing the logic of the rest of the code so that it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should have both the lines enclosed in `if` condition:

```
if(taskArr[i] != null)
{
    taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
    taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use curly brackets (`{}`) in your if clause. If you don't, just the line under the condition is recognized:

```
if(taskArr[i] != null) {
    taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
    taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you check if `taskArr` is empty, then try to extract a value from `taskId`. It is possible `taskId` is `null`, or at least the value from that. You need to check that likewise.

Try this:

```
for int(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(taskArray[i].getText() != null) //Check if Text from taskArray[i] is null
        taskArr[i] = taskArray[i].getText().toString();
    if(taskArray[i].getId != null) //Check if ID from taskArray[i] is null
        taskId[i] = taskArray[i].getId();
}
```

Comment: I tried if(taskId[i] != null but the code gets a syntax error

Comment: @Anthony Wu Sorry I overlooked something. Can you try this code?